# Would there be any current if an electric circuit is cooled to absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, superconductivity, low-temperature-physics

My question is if I got a superconductor and cool it to absolute zero at least measurable by today's tool, it should have no electrical resistance but then would there be any current when there is a voltage potential diff?

Comment: Are you asking because of ohm's law of I = V/R?

Comment: @spcan: not exactly, I asked because I thought there should be no movement at absolute zero at least measurable one but then resistance also become zero

Comment: It's not really absolute zero, just a few Kelvin or fraction of Kelvin over zero so there is some movement. And some materials are superconductors at even higher temperatures. The only property that characterizes a superconductor is its almost zero resistance.

Comment: @spcan Absolute zero $T$ does not mean no movement. It means no _thermal_ movement. A beam of particles all moving at the same speed has zero temperature.